# meta_query 'compare' => 'IN' not working

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

First of all, I know it's a duplicate, but none of the older answers were helpful.

I'm searching in posts through `post_meta`. Here's my code, which currently returns nothing.

```
$args   =   array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'system_power_supply',
            'value'     => array('single', 'redundant'),
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        )
    )

);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
echo $query->found_posts;
```

If I remove `meta_query` it works. I'm sure of these things:

- There's no spelling mistake in the `key` or the `value`.
- post type is `post`
- There **is** a post with the value 'single' in 'system_power_supply'. However, post fields are generated by [Advanced Custom Fields](http://advancedcustomfields.com).

Comment: is `system_power_supply` serialized?

Comment: yes, it is. Here's the value in postmeta table 

`a:1:{i:0;s:6:"single";}`

Comment: well that's your problem, meta query won't work on serialized data. if you search this site for querying serialized data you'll find some answers, but no method will be ideal.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no easy way to search serialized values in a meta query. If the list of values isn't crazy long, potentially you could set up multiple meta queries:

```
'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'       => 'system_power_supply',
        'value'     => 'single',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'system_power_supply',
        'value'     => 'redundant',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
    )
)
```

Or if you wanted to get super fancy, you could set it up dynamically:

```
$values_to_search = array('single', 'redundant');
$meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
foreach ($values_to_search as $value) {
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'       => 'system_power_supply',
        'value'     => $value,
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, bro. I can't tell you how big headache you've solved of mine.

Comment: btw, why the meta_value containing serialized data if we're not able to query through meta_query ? Is this wordpress's bug?

Comment: I'm a woman, not a "bro", but no problem. The meta_value contains serialized data because of the way Advanced Custom Fields saves the data. It's not ideal, for sure.

Comment: BTW, which solution worked for you?

Comment: haha, I apologize my lady. Second and third worked well, didn't try the first one.

Comment: It's unusual to see a lady programmer, who don't bite at all :D

Comment: you can remove the first one, it doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

I know it's been a long time, but just in case someone has the same issue. Well i've been pulling my hair for hours before i found the issue: 'meta_query' with 'IN' comparison operator doesn't seem to accept the usual array. instead, you need to join it first with ', '.

So, in your case, something like this should work :

```
$args   =   array(
'posts_per_page'   => -1,
'post_type'     => 'post',
'meta_query'    => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'system_power_supply',
        'value'     => join(', ', array('single', 'redundant')),
        'compare'   => 'IN',
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
echo $query->found_posts;
```

Comment: In WP 5 you can just pass the array directly to the value key. If you implode it to a string you may get unexpected results in regards to how wp splits the string up into segments for the `IN()` part. Eg, `'this that', 'and', 'that'` becomes `'this','that','and','that'` - so seems to be better to just give it the array.